# Making Windows 7 On-Screen Keyboard popup more noticeable?

Tags: windows-7, kiosk, on-screen-keyboard

We are trying to deploy a self contained touch screen kiosk running Windows 7 and through much headache and hours of tweaking were able to lock it down rather well.  The only remaining issue we are facing are the current usability issues with the On-Screen Keyboard popup.

We cannot permanently keep the keyboard displayed on the screen as the user could just close it and they have no way of opening it again.  We configured it so that when the input field gets focus this tiny, barely noticeable blue bar appears on the left center of the screen.  Only when you touch this bar does it pull out slightly to where it reveals what looks like the end of a keyboard.

The problem is that our users, to be as polite as possible, are technically challenged, so they will have no idea what that little blue bar means and will likely not notice it.  The little pull out image of the right side of a keyboard is far and away better and I was hoping we could default when an input box gets focus for this to be shown instead.

If this is impossible to do through configuration then does anybody know of a software that can replace the Windows 7 On-Screen keyboard and still have keyboard popup on input box focus?  We are unconcerned with free and are willing to spend money if that makes a difference.